# Animating text disappearance - like cleaning blackboard

Tags: iphone, core-animation

How can I animate UILabel to disappear like the text would be cleaned from blackboard? The animation is like hiding pieces of text rectangle with couple shape animations. Is it possible with Core Animation? I don't really want OpenGL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rotate the `mask` property of your `UILabel`'s `layer` between different states of your prerendered "clear" animation.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on 'prerendered' part?

Comment: For each frame in the animation, create a mask image representing that stage of the animation. First frame would be completely opaque; last frame would be completely transparent; in between frames would have various amounts of the blackboard erased.

Comment: and to make actual animation in mask, have some timer and change `contents` on each tick or there is a better way?

Comment: If you want to use a UILabel, yes. You could generate the mask images at runtime, but that will could be slow

Comment: Also, don't change `contents`. Change `mask`.

Comment: You mean a frame by frame animation, right? With one pre-rendered image per frame...

What type of image would yield the best performance? If you want to clear the whole view of the phone, I would think you would probably need 1 second at 20fps to get a fairly smooth animation...

Comment: A single-channel mask for each frame will yield the best performance. I don't think it needs to be full resolution if you don't mind it being blurry.